# Why does DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value not display the assigned value

Tags: c#, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor, selecteditem

I have an `Asp: Dropdownlist`. I want to display a selected list item based on an assigned value.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="uxRegionDropDownList" runat="server" style="height:25px; width: 34%; text-align: center;" required="False">
     <asp:ListItem Value="-1">FEMA Region</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">I</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">II</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3">III</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="4">IV</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="5">V</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="6">VI</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="7">VII</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="8">VIII</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="9">IX</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="10">X</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="HQ">HQ</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Unknown">Unknown</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

For example, if I have a variable `string region = "9"`, and assigned `uxRegionDropDownList = region`, I would expect that it would populate `IX` as the selected value. However, it does not. It just displays "FEMA Region". How can I resolve this and make the correct `ListItem` display in the box?

**C#**

```
protected void uxStatesDropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateCountiesList(uxStatesDropdownList.SelectedValue);
        UpdateRegion(uxStatesDropdownList.SelectedValue);

    }
private void UpdateRegion(string stateName)
    {
        string region = _dtMgr.GetFEMARegionByState(stateName);
        //uxRegionDropDownList.Items.Clear();
        uxRegionDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value = region;

    }
```

Note: In the above scenario, I change the state to 'AR' which returns a region = "9" as a string.

Comment: At first I think you should use  `onselectedindexchanged="uxStatesDropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged"` in drop down tag

Comment: stateName == 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `uxRegionDropDownList.SelectedValue = region;` instead.

The current code would change the value of the currently selected item, whereas you seem to want to change the currently selected item based on a value. The `SelectedValue` property will either get the currently selected item's value, or select an item with the value provided.

Comment: I ended up changing it to `.SelectedValue` (which I had previously tried without success), but added @hassan.ef 's suggestion as well. Thanks.